# Javascript replace words (not part of word) in cyryllic

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find some cyrrilic words (only words, not part of another word) in cyrillic string and replace them to another. But I can't find solution to this case.

In English it works:

```
'Slipknot not NOT'.replace(/\bNot\b/gi, 'TEST') // Slipknot TEST TEST
```

But not in cyryllic string:

```
'целине не НЕ'.replace(/\bНе\b/gi, 'TEST') // still 'целине не НЕ'
```

I know that "/b" is not for cyrillic. 
I found this solution:

```
'целине не НЕ'.replace(/\Не(?![A-я])/gi, 'ТЕСТ'); //"целиТЕСТ ТЕСТ ТЕСТ" when I want "целине TЕСТ ТЕСТ"
```

But it replaced part of word, and I do not need to replace parts of words.

Comment: Your range for Cyrillic (Russian here) letters does not include `ё` and `Ё`. Are you working with Russian alphabet only?

Comment: You need to mimic the look-behind: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript. For your case`.replace(/(^|[^A-я])Не(?![A-я])/gi, '$1TECT')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word boundary `\b` in JS cannot be used to detect the word boundary of Unicode letters. It can be achieved with a capturing group containing the alternation matching the start of string or any non-word (non-Russian, non-Latin, non-digit, non-underscore) character and after the word, a negative look-ahead checking the absence of this range. In the replacement part, we need to restore the matched and captured text before the word with the `$1` back-reference.

```js
document.write('целине не НЕ'.replace(/(^|[^A-ZА-ЯЁ0-9_])Не(?![A-ZА-ЯЁ0-9_])/gi, '$1ТЕСТ'));
```

Note that `Ё` does not belong to `[А-Яа-я]` (or even `[А-я]`) range, thus we need to add it separately.

**UPDATE**

To answer your question in comments,

> `'целине не НЕ нетак'.replace(/(^|[^A-ZА-ЯЁ0-9_])Не(?= )/gi, '$1TECT') //"целине TECT TECT нетак"` when I should get `целине ТЕСТТЕСТнетак`

The trouble here is that you need to *match* (=consume) the space after the `Не`, but the space may be necessary to identify the word boundary for the subsequent match. In this case, you can rely on a string reversal work-around:

```js
function revStr(str) {
    return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}
var s = 'целине не НЕ нетак';
var repl = 'ТЕСТ';
document.write(
           revStr(
             revStr(s).replace(/ еН(?=$|[^A-ZА-ЯЁ0-9_])/gi, revStr(repl))
           ));
```

Comment: Sorry. I just took a look at the specs, and it seems that ES6 doesn't have support for Unicode short-hand syntax.

Comment: @nhahtdh: OK, I see, I also thought it included that change.

Comment: @stribizhev thanks, and one more question: if I need find not just "не", but "не " with white space after this?

Comment: Then, I think the task is even simpler: `/(^|[^A-ZА-ЯЁ0-9_])Не(?= )/gi`. The positive look-ahead `(?= )` will require a space after `не` (though the space won't be "consumed" as it is a zero-width assertion).

Comment: @stribizhev yes, it works, but this will not replace the whitespace at the end. "'целине не НЕ нетак'.replace(/(^|[^A-ZА-ЯЁ0-9_])Не(?= )/gi, '$1TECT') //"целине TECT TECT нетак"" when I should get "целине ТЕСТТЕСТнетак"

Comment: This is a case when you need a look-behind only. Perhaps, reverting a string is a possible approach here. I have updated the post. If I find another work-around, I will post another update.